# Why are there files and functions that works in my project but their code does not exist in the project itself

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

When I click on my profile on my website I get a menu of options like change email/password, add 2FA, and more. to make it work I used Identity and added the things mentioned before. But now when I try to locate the code for the menu I cannot find it.

The only code I could find is called `_ManageNav.cshtml` and contains some functions but no code.

```
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@{
    var hasExternalLogins = (await SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).Any();
}
<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link @ManageNavPages.IndexNavClass(ViewContext)" id="profile" asp-page="./Index">Profile</a>    </li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link @ManageNavPages.EmailNavClass(ViewContext)" id="email" asp-page="./Email">Email</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link @ManageNavPages.ChangePasswordNavClass(ViewContext)" id="change-password" asp-page="./ChangePassword">Password</a></li>
    @if (hasExternalLogins)
    {
        <li id="external-logins" class="nav-item"><a id="external-login" class="nav-link @ManageNavPages.ExternalLoginsNavClass(ViewContext)" asp-page="./ExternalLogins">External logins</a></li>
    }
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link @ManageNavPages.TwoFactorAuthenticationNavClass(ViewContext)" id="two-factor" asp-page="./TwoFactorAuthentication">Two-factor authentication</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link @ManageNavPages.PersonalDataNavClass(ViewContext)" id="personal-data" asp-page="./PersonalData">Personal data</a></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, there is a direction for each function but nothing after that.
I am asking this because I want to change some buttons' appearance on the screen in the 2FA authentication. 
For this example, After I completed a 2FA process I still have the buttons for the setup process, and I want them removed.
[image]

You can see In the image that I am in the link `localhost:44392/Identity/Account/Manage/TwoFactorAuthentication` so logically the code is in a file called `TwoFactorAuthentication.cshtml`, but there are no files with this name.

I have tried to research the web for an answer and I could not find anything related to the `TwoFactorAuthentication` file on this entire profile page.

I would like to ask for an explanation of where the code for this entire  (profile customization) page is located and how to access it and edit its code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize the pages used by Identity you need to [Scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio).

To scaffold when Identity is already setup:

> - From Solution Explorer, right-click on the project > Add > New Scaffolded Item.
> - From the left pane of the Add New Scaffolded Item dialog, select Identity. Select Identity in the center pane.

When done, you can edit the files that have been added to the project.

For example, to get the `TwoFactorAuthentication.cshtml` scaffolded, you select "Account\Manager\TwoFactorAuthentication" in the Add Identity dialog.

The scaffolded files will be located under `Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage`.

Comment: Yes, I added all the things from the Identity just like how you said, but I don't see the option for the main menu.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I don't see the option for the main menu". I've just run the command line version on my Linux machine and it generated "WebUi/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/TwoFactorAuthentication.cshtml" and a bunch of other files under WebUi/Areas/Identity. Didn't you get files generated there?

Comment: What identities have you added?

Comment: I just ran "dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity" from the command line so I guess that scaffolded everything. I'll have a look and see how it behaves when doing the scaffolding in VS 2022 on Windows.

Comment: Hey, no need, I found that identity, but when I applied it, now when I click on the profile it throws some error. I will add it right away.

Comment: Quick update, I wrote the last comment while cloning the GitHub repo before the changes and I added it again and somehow it works fine. The final edit/update will come out soon. Thank you a lot btw :)